# Firing an change event from JavaScript

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<input name="X">
```

and in JavaScript:

```
$('input').on('change','[name=X]',function() {
        $('body').append('on change fired!');
    }
);
$('input[name=X]').change(function() {
    $('body').append('change fired!');
});
$(input[name='X']).val('test');
```

But my problem is that neither change event gets fired.

Comment: Have you put your codes within the `$(document).ready`?

Comment: It's at the end of the html just above the /body.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code, you have missed the quotes for the `input` selector.

Comment: @undefined that's what I thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the value of an input element programatically will not trigger any event. Alternatively, You can call `.change` after `.val` like below,

```
$('input[name=X]').val('test').change();
```

**Edit:** Also fixed the missing quotes around the input selector.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/G6n4h/1/

Comment: Your fiddle also helped me with my other syntax problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are missing quotes around your selector, plus how about adding trigger?

```
$("input[name='X']").val("test").trigger("change");
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rNMvZ/)

Comment: @Gabe how would it differentiate between a selector and a variable? I thought all jquery selectors require quotes around them!

Comment: I was saying quotes are not required for that attribute value selector. `"input[name=X]"` or `"input[name='X']"`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using a ready block

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WVv6e/)

```
$(function(){
   $('input').on('change','[name=X]',function() {
        $('body').append('on change fired!');
   });
   $('input[name=X]').change(function() {
       $('body').append('change fired!');
   });
   $(input[name='X']).val('test'); 
});
```

​
If you're trying to simply trigger is programmatically:

```
$('input[name=X]').change(); // trigger change event
```

Comment: Oh, I thought it would be automatic.

Comment: No, you're creating a handler for change, not triggering the change event.

Comment: But I thought changing the value would automatically trigger the change event.

Comment: @Phillip Changing the value of an input element programatically **will not** trigger any event.